# c++/ubuntu - templates error

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following code:
file.h:

```
#ifndef __ANA_H__
#define __ANA_H__

template <class T>
class ana {

class ana1{//code
          }*anna1;

  public: 
    bool method(T& data,ana::ana1 &a);
};

#endif
```

file.cpp:

```
#include <ana.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
bool ana<T>::method(T& data,ana::ana1 &t) {
  cout << "Data = " << data << endl;
  if(data > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I have error: `ana::ana1 is not a type`. How to resolve this error? where am i wrong? need some help.thx
i am working in ubuntu and i compile the code using g++. i create an .a from the .h and .cpp i've posted.

Comment: Names like `__ANA_H__`, which contain underscores, or start with an underscore are not allowed in user-written code. Change it to `ANA_H`

Comment: @unapersson : Containing underscores is fine; containing *two consecutive* underscores is the problem (as well as starting with one of course).

Comment: @ildjam Indeed - that's what I meant, but obviously didn't type.

Answer (score 2):

Make that

```
// (declaration):
bool method(T& data, ana1& t);
```

and

```
// (definition):
bool ana<T>::method(T& data, typename ana<T>::ana1& t) {
```

Comment: ana1 is a subclass from ana. I can;t just have ana1. i need ana::ana1,no?

Comment: @linuxx: It's not a subclass, it is a nested class.

Comment: @linuxx : Just replace the relevant lines *you* pasted with the lines *I* pasted. Why should I need to re-paste the entirety of your code?

Comment: you are right.thx! i keep have the ana::ana1 is not a type:(. please help!

Comment: @linuxx : If your code is using `ana::ana1` anywhere, then you didn't make the changes I suggested.

Comment: i've replaced ana::ana1& t with ana1& t but i still have the same error: ana::ana1&t is not a type.

Comment: i just want the definition of the method in the .h file!

Comment: @linuxx : If you can't copy and paste the lines I posted over the ones you have, then I simply don't know how to help you.

Comment: My code is much more complicated. It contains a lot of nested classes. I did replace my code with what you suggested but i still have the same error. do you know why? It's true i do use ana::ana1 in other methods too. In the method i've posted i just need a GENERIC OBJECT! As i've seen this is the only solution! PLEASE HELP! I need to call a generic object

Comment: I need to have only the definition of the method in the .h file. The code that the method containes is in the .cpp code.

Answer (score 2):

With templates you should put [declaration and definition into the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). This could look like this in your case:

```
#ifndef __ANA_H__
#define __ANA_H__

template <class T>
class ana {

class ana1{//code
          }*anna1;

  public: 
    bool method(T& data,ana1 &a) {
        cout << "Data = " << data << endl;
        if(data > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

#endif
```